# How can I launch hdfs on Mesos without DC/OS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-mesos

From my understand DC/OS is a freemium managed service. Because I'd rather just have a raw Mesos implementation, I'd rather not be dependent on DC/OS and so I just want to know how to implement HDFS on Mesos without it.

Unfortunately google is dominated by mesosphere DC/OS. Is there anyway I can compile for myself an HDFS implementation onto mesos without DC/OS dependencies?

Comment: I've been asking the very same question lately. Thanks for asking it here! (Why did I not think about it?!)

Comment: So after doing some research, the only way to build hdfs on mesos is to use their deprecated repo https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs-deprecated. From what I understand, they built a special scheduler and executor not available from hadoop. Furthermore, their new hdfs mod is not publicly available nor open source as they promised last year. Instead it's in the DC/OS package that they force you to use.

I will later post an entire answer when I get this actually running and will probably blog about it on Linkedin.